# Video tutorials: how to add labels, comments, arrows etc

Tags: video, software

I'm planning to make a video tutorial about one application. I would like to make it without speaking, but I would like to add comments to video.

Is there a video software that allows you to add comments, labels, arrows etc.. to clarify and highlight some things in the video.

Wink seemed like one, but it is only available for linux as 32 bit binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use Youtube's video editing tools to add annotations and comments. Thanks to other comments!

Answer (score 1):

[Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) (and many others) is such a software (for Windows, you didn't state OS).

It's a screen recorder which in post allow you to add labels, pop-outs, arrows, text-boxes, zooms and pans etc, as well as letting you do basic editing.

I am recommending this one because I have personal experience with it, but that isn't to say other similar software isn't as good or worse/better.